# html/php dropdown not working correctly

Tags: php, html

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="signin.php" class="dropbtn">Account</a>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['on'])) {
      echo '<a href="logout.php">Log out</a>';
    }
    else if (!isset($_SESSION['on'])) {
      echo '<a href="signin.php">Sign in</a>';
      echo '<a href="signup.php">Sign up</a>';
    }
  ?>
  </div>
</li>
```

So what this is supposed to do is when ur not signed in u get to see the signin and signup dropdown buttons and not the logout. This part works. But as soon as u log in, in stead of showing the log out button and nothing else, it only shows the sign in and sign up buttons. How do i fix this?

Comment: Your `else if` is totally redundant; just use `else`. Have you called `session_start()` before this (or any other) HTML output?

Comment: on the log in page u start the session. And yes the else if i get why it's redundant. I was trying so many things to try and make it work. Do i need to start the session on every page? i thought when u start session once then u have started it until u logout

Comment: How do you _"login"_? Does it cause this page to be reloaded?

Comment: https://justforkicks.000webhostapp.com/index.php that's the link. I don't know how to explain it because i just started with coding

Comment: PHP executes on the Server when the page loads, therefore if the Session is the result of an Asynchronous Sever Call *(AJAX)*, the PHP is not reread on the page you are on. So, if you're using AJAX, which you should be, then you should put your PHP on a Separate Page where you test your `$_SESSION` info.

Comment: I suggest you actually read the documentation ~ [_"`session_start()` creates a session or **resumes the current one**"_](http://php.net/manual/function.session-start.php)

Comment: I'm not usually one to provide W3Schools links but this is actually a pretty decent starter tutorial ~ https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Answer (score 2):

session_start needs to be available to start or get a session, this needs to be placed at the beginning of your php on the page.  If you are checking isset the else is already the result of what will happen if session is not set, so i removed

```
else if (!isset($_SESSION['on']))
```

and replaced it with a simple else.

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['on'])) {
  echo '<a href="logout.php">Log out</a>';
} else {
  echo '<a href="signin.php">Sign in</a>';
  echo '<a href="signup.php">Sign up</a>';
}
```

Remember to go back and use the session_start() on the page where you set the sessions to begin with.